# Operator norm for $\|x\|=1$ and $\|x\|<1$

Tags: normed-spaces, operator-theory, supremum-and-infimum

let $T:X \to Y$ be a bounded linear map. $X$ and $Y$ are two normed vector space. Each norm is denoted by $\| \cdot \|_X$ and $\| \cdot \|_Y$

define its operator norm by $$\|T\|_\text{op}=\sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|T_x\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}$$
The book said that

> $$\|T\|_\text{op}=\sup_{\|x\|_X=1} \|T_x\|_Y = \sup_{\|x\|_X \le 1}\|T_x\|_Y $$

I can understand the first equation, but have no idea about the second equation.

Comment: It turns out that all these definitions are equivalent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\| \le \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\|$ holds immediately due to the definition of supremum. So it suffices to show the reverse inequality.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon < \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\|$. Then there exists $x_\epsilon$ satisfying $\|x_\epsilon\| \le 1$ such that $\|Tx_\epsilon\| \ge \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\| - \epsilon > 0$. We cannot have $x_\epsilon = 0$ else $\|Tx_\epsilon\| = 0$; thus $x_\epsilon \ne 0$. Then defining $\tilde{x}_\epsilon := x_\epsilon / \|x_\epsilon\|$ we have
$$\|T\tilde{x}_\epsilon\|
= \|Tx_\epsilon\| / \|x_\epsilon\|
\ge \|Tx_\epsilon\| \ge \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\| - \epsilon.$$
Taking the supremum over the left-hand side over $\|x\|=1$ we obtain
$$\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\| \ge \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\| - \epsilon.$$
The above argument holds for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, so we have
$$\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\| \ge \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Tx\|.$$

Comment: I don't understand why the first inequality holds, sorry.

Comment: @Halk If $A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are subsets of the real numbers, then $\sup A \le \sup B$.

Comment: oh yes, thanks!

Comment: Surly a duplicate. Has been answered in the very eaarly stages of MSE.